# How do put in this color in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, figma

An element in a figma file I have has a color specified as:

```
#FFFFFF 9%
#121212 100%
```

How do I put in this color in Android Studio? I'm trying to use it as a background color for a Linear Layout.

[image]

Comment: you can directly set layout background with that color using attribute `android:background = "#FFFFFF"`

Comment: Where do I set the opacity?

Comment: opacity option will also be available there.

Answer (score 0):

Set below colors in the res/values/colors.xml file

```
<color name="color1">#17FFFFFF</color>
<color name="color2">#121212</color>
```

and you got the same result as the Figma document

Comment: Without defining them in colors.xml? Using the GUI...